# Artifact seems to be removed during source code checkout

Tags: bamboo, bamboo-artifacts

I have an artifact dependency, the artifact being created by a previous stage in the plan. As 'destination directory' for the dependency, I have put 'Artifacts'.

There is a task that just runs the script line `dir Artifacts`. This works fine, and in the logs I can see that the artifact is in the 'Artifacts' directory. This task is followed by a source code checkout task. The source code checkout is then followed by a task which, again, just runs `dir Artifacts`. This time, it gives an error message because, as it seems, the 'Artifacts' directory does not exist anymore.

I can see in the logs that, as part of the source code checkout, Bamboo "cleans" the build directory. I suppose this removes the 'Artifacts' directory. But if that is the case, how can I use Artifacts after doing a source code checkout?

Comment: Reorder your tasks and download the artifact from the previous stage after the source code checkout task.